# Java Time2 Going from 3 integers to a single integer

Tags: java

I am trying to change my time2 class from having 3 integers to a single integer to save space. I have gotten rid of hour, minute, and second and now just have totalseconds to represent the time since midnight. I replaced it in the set and get methods as well as in the 3 argument constructor and it runs in the Time2Test app but is only reading seconds. All three of the arguments are being read as seconds so I am not sure what is happening. ex- Time2Test time should read 12:25:42 but instead reads as 42:42:42. First is the Time2 class then I have also added Time2Test for clarity. Any direction would be appreciated.

```
public class Time2 {
    private int totalseconds;
    //no argument constructor
    public Time2()
    {
        this(0,0,0); //invoke constructor with three arguments default to 0
    }

    //constructor with hour supplied minute and second default to 0
    public Time2(int hour)
    {
        this(hour, 0, 0); //invoke constructor with 3 args
    }

    //constructor with hour and minute supplied seconds default to 0
    public Time2(int hour, int minute)
    {
        this(hour, minute, 0); //invoke constructor with 3 args
    }

    //Time2 constructor with hour minute and second supplied also tests

    public Time2(int hour, int minute, int second)
    {       
        this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
        this.totalseconds = (minute * 60);
        this.totalseconds = (second);
    }

    public Time2(Time2 time)
    {
        //invoke constructor with 2 args
        this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());
    }

    // SET and GET methods start here, also Universal time conversion and check
    public void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second) 
    {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-23");
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute must be 0-59");
        if (second < 0 || second >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-59");

         this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
         this.totalseconds = (minute * 60);
         this.totalseconds = (second);
    }

    //validate and set hour
    public void setHour(int hour)
    {
        if (hour < 0 || hour >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hour must be 0-23");
        this.totalseconds = (hour * 3600);
    }

    //validate and set minute
    public void setMinute(int minute)
    {
        if (minute < 0 || minute >= 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Minute must be 0-59");
        this.totalseconds = (minute * 60);
    }

    //validate and set second
    public void setSecond(int second)
    {
        if (second < 0 || second >= 24)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second must be 0-59");
        this.totalseconds = (second);
    }
    //Get Methods start here

    //Get hour
    public int getHour()
    {
        return totalseconds % 3600;
    }

    //get minute
    public int getMinute()
    {
        return totalseconds % 60;
    }

    //get second
    public int getSecond()
    {
        return totalseconds;
    }

    //convert our string to universal format (HH:MM:SS)
    public String ToUniversalString()
    {
        return String.format(
        "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
    }

    //conver to standard format (H:MM:SS AM or PM)
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s",((getHour() == 0 || getHour() ==
        12) ? 12 : getHour() % 12), getMinute(), getSecond(), (getHour()
        < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
    }
}//end class Time2



package time2;

public class Time2Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Time2 t1 = new Time2(); //00:00:00
        Time2 t2 = new Time2(2); //02:00:00 
        Time2 t3 = new Time2(21, 34); //21:34:00
        Time2 t4 = new Time2(12, 25, 42); //12:25:42
        Time2 t5 = new Time2(t4); //12:25:42

        System.out.println("Constructed with:");
        displayTime("t1: all default arguments", t1);
        displayTime("t2: hour specified; defaults for minute and second", t2);
        displayTime("t3: hour and minute supplied second defaulted", t3);
        displayTime("t4: hour minute and second supplied", t4);
        displayTime("t5: Time2 object t4 specified", t5);

        //attempt to initialize t6 with invalid args
        try
        {
            Time2 t6 = new Time2(27,74,99); //all invalid values
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.printf("%nException while initializing t6: %s%n",
                    e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    //display Time2 object in 24 hour and 12 hour formats
    private static void displayTime(String header, Time2 t)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s%n   %s%n   %s%n", header, t.ToUniversalString(),
                t.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: suppose you are not assigning the `totalseconds` the sum of seconds since midnight and calculatons seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You repeatedly do the following:

```
this.totalSeconds = (hour * 3600);
this.totalSeconds = (minute * 60);
this.totalSeconds = second;
```

This effectively overwrites itself three times, so only the final value is observed.

What you're looking for is

```
this.totalSeconds = (hour * 3600);
this.totalSeconds += (minute * 60);
this.totalSeconds += second;
```

Otherwise you're just overwriting it on each line.

---

Additionally, you use `%` to compute the hours/minutes.  This won't work, for example, if total seconds is 3672 (1 hour, 1 minute, 12 seconds).

3672 % 3600 = 72.  That's not how many hours there are.

For hours, you want `totalSeconds / 3600`; for minutes `(totalSeconds - (3600 * getHours())) / 60`, and for seconds `totalSeconds - (3600 * getHours()) - (60 * getMinutes())`.

Sorry for edits, it's late and I can't math.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what you mean by over writing it. That isn't something I had run into yet in coding but makes perfect sense. Thanks again!